# How to manage Databricks SQL Endpoints from application / command line?

Tags: databricks, databricks-sql

Is there a way to start, stop, list available SQL Endpoints in [Databricks SQL](https://databricks.com/product/databricks-sql)?

---

With "Can Use" permission it's possible to start a SQL Endpoint while connecting to an endpoint using the Databricks JDBC driver, but have no idea how to stop it (not to mention how to list all the available endpoints).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of this (and more) could be done via [REST API for SQL Endpoints](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/api/sql-endpoints.html).  You just need to be authenticated to workspace & have corresponding permissions.  To stop you need to have `CAN_MANAGE` permission (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/user/security/access-control/sql-endpoint-acl#sql-endpoint-permissions))

Comment: Yup, found it myself too and works great! I must admit it gives better view on the underlying configuration that the UI itself. Wish there were `dbutils`-way of managing SQL endpoints.

Comment: for actual management (except start/stop), I would recommend to use Databricks Terraform provider